# Encountered Error regarding bootstrap-alert.js in javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded bootstrap.zip and included in my html page like this `<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>`
and my Html code has
`<div class="alert fade in">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
            <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
          </div>`
I am getting
bootstrap-alert.js:75     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you include jQuery as well. Bootstrap-alert.js depends on receiving a reference to the window.jQuery object as a parameter.